# PHP Tonic Services - Using the same verb more than once in the same service

Tags: php, rest

I started looking at the [Tonic Restful Services framework](https://github.com/peej/tonic#readme) and I really think it's a very nice framework. The problem is that I cannot find much resources apart from the examples in order to see possible ways of using it.

I would like for example to know if I could use the POST verb more than one time in a single resource and if there is some sort of annotation that could allow me to do that. For example JAX-RS have the @Action annotation.

I really do not have a lot of experience with REST or PHP so I really need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between the behavior of the different POST methods you want?

Comment: What's stopping you from trying it out and seeing for yourself?

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. But you can route your posts using another variable in your posts requests.
Just make sure to clean methods name for security reasons...

something like this.

```
   /**
     * Handle a POST request for this resource
     * @param Request request
     * @return Response
     */
    function post($request) {

        if (isset($_POST['method'])) {
           return $this->$method($request, $name);
        }

    } 

    function post_one($request) {
       // your code here
    }

    function post_two($request) {
       // your code here
    }

    //...and so on...
```

If you want to check if method exists, you could use something like

```
if (method_exists('controller_name', 'method_name'));
```

But that's another topic. http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php